# Create a virutalenv on another drive - Access is denied

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, virtualenv

When trying to create a virtual env on my main drive (C:\) it works fine, but on my second disk (E:\) I get a error saying:

> ERROR: The executable "E:\path\env\Scripts\python.exe" could not be
>   run: [WinError 5] Access is denied.

The command I'm using is:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>virtualenv "E:\path to project\env"
>
> Or
>
> E:\path to project>virtualenv env

It does create the folder, but it looks like when it's trying to run python to install all of the requirement for the virtualenv it fails.

I'm using python 3.5 which is installed at its default location on C:\.

- I tried using another version (3.4).
- run the command as an administrator.
- making a symbolic link and create the env from there.
- run the command from c:\

Nothing seems to work.

I'm kind of out of ideas. Those anybody have the same problem or a solution?
It's kind of annoying having to work on my c:\ as it's almost out of space.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the exact command you're using to try to create the virtualenv.

Comment: Try the venv module instead, e.g. `python -m venv E:\path to project\env`.

Comment: Yes venv works fine thank you

Comment: Can we get the working comment added as an Answer and marked?  Just burned an hour and a half trying to find this.

Answer (score 2):

To quote Eryk Sun in the comment above, I thought I would put his answer here because it should be the accepted solution:

```
python -m venv E:\path to project\env
```